# Perl : opening a pipe : No such file or directory

Tags: perl, pipe

I'm having troubles with opening a pipe to redirect the output of a dir command. The error happens in svn.pm, which is a part of the Windows debugging SDK and is intended to support source indexing for subversion repositories. The section where it goes wrong is:

```
my $hProcess;

if ( ! open($hProcess, "dir $SourceRoot 2>&1 |") ) {
    ::warn_message("Unable to resolve directory: $!");
    return();
}
```

[download]

`$SourceRoot` is an existing directory. The error that I get back via `$!` is "No such file or directory". The whole purpose of the above script (I did not write it, and I'm not a Perl developer) is to get all source files in a directory and process those. Any idea?

Comment: just print $SourceRoot in if.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html

Comment: Calling a `dir` command is inefficient. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Two most likely causes: 1) There's a space or other meta character in `$SourceRoot`, or 2) this is a cygwin `perl` that doesn't have the hack to pretend `dir` and other `cmd` internals are actual programs

Comment: @Sobrique : like mentioned I did not develop the script, it is existing code (part of the symbol store which is part of the Windows SDK debugging kit). That particular part of the code is believed to get all source files in $SourceRoot and put them in a pipe for later processing using SVN commands to get their revision number. This is a part of the source indexing where revision numbers are stored in the PDB symbol files so that they can be pulled automatically from the SVN source database when examining a dump file.

Comment: @ikegami : no spaces (directory passed by $Sourceroot is C:\Crash) and I installed active perl (installed latest version 2 weeks ago)

Answer (score 2):

Why not instead:

```
my @directory_entries = glob ( "$SourceRoot/*" );
```

Or:

```
opendir ( my $dir_handle, $SourceRoot ); 
while ( my $entry = readdir ( $dir_handle ) ) {
   print $entry; 
}
```

Comment: `glob( "$SourceRoot/*" )` would require escaping many characters.